# Calling a function through buttons in ASP.NET using VB

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm having some issues with calling the function I have defined when I click a button. For example, my function is something like this:

```
<script runat = "server" language = "vb">

Sub deleteFunction()
    Response.Write("hello test test")
End Sub

</script>
```

This is all within the `<head>` tags. In the `<body>` tags, I have this:

```
<form method = "post" action = "HubPage.aspx">
    <input type = "submit" value = "Delete" onclick = "<% deleteFunction() %>">
</form>
```

That doesn't work because it just calls the function without me ever having to click the button. So I tried this:

```
<form method = "post" action = "HubPage.aspx" onsubmit = "<% deleteFunction() %>">
    <input type = "submit" value = "Delete">
</form>
```

However, that also calls the function regardless.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `onsubmit` calls a client side functions. Your `delete` function is server side. I suggest looking at some beginner ASP.net tutorials. Hint , you will need to use an `<asp:Button>` control and have a click handler for it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: Thanks, this led me to my solution, but I ended up scrapping it and did something different.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove onclick event and but this in your .Net code to call javascript code

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, Nothing, "FunctionName();", True)
```